# Is there a way to stack `Tabs` vertically?

Tags: tabs, codenameone

I was looking at the `Tabs` option for a UI. The default behavior is that they are stacked horizontally. Is there a way to change that?
I would like to stack the `Tabs` vertically. It would save significant UI "real estate", especially in mobile application UIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Tabs tabs = new Tabs(Component.LEFT)
```